# MongoDB Atlas - Understanding timestamps differences between Atlas GUI and the Logs downloaded file

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, timezone, mongodb-atlas

***TL;DR***

*Why there is a difference between the *MongoDB Atlas Download Logs GUI* and the downloaded logs file regarding the timestamp?*

*DETAIL:*

I'd like to know about the difference between time (date, hour, minutes) between emails from alerts, the Atlas GUI and the time shown in the downloadable logs, as I think is important to be able to locate precisely an event in the log without doubts.

I'll use this example to be able to understand:

Using *MongoDB Atlas*, I got a Cluster that whose region is **AWS / N. Virginia (us-east-1)**.
I've received an email alert that states an issue occurred at **2020/07/22 12:11 EDT**.
I'd like to check the logs to be able to analyze the issue, so I go to `Mongo DB Atlas > Clusters > ... > Download Logs` and I select the date and time from the email alert as follows:

[image: MongoDB Atlas - Download Logs GUI]

When I download the logs file, I got a range of dates from *2020-07-22T15:57:55.910+0000* to *2020-07-22T16:27:55.825+0000* I'm trying to understand that difference.

I know I could search in the logs for 16:11 records instead of 12:11 ones but I'd like to understand the difference. Why I didn't get from 12:00 to 12:30 and I got 16:00 to 16:30 instead? Where does that difference comes from?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4 hour difference is, surely, your timezone offset. I'm guessing the UI shows times  in local time for you and the actual logs are in UTC.

The 00:00 vs 57:55.910 situation has to do with how atlas logs are handled internally - they are basically pulled from the nodes every 5 or so minutes and the pull times are not snapped to grid, so they just happen every 5 minutes since exact time that the cluster or node launched as far as I am aware. When you get the logs you get them in the chunks that the internal tooling uses to retrieve them which are generally not aligned to the times you specify (in UI or using the Atlas API).

Comment: UTC is used for logs as stated in the docs indded: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/logs/ According to this: https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?qm=1&lid=306,5,100&h=5&date=2020-7-22&sln=13-13.5 I'm currently in CDT timezone, the Atlas GUI has the EST timezone (the cluster one it seems) and the logs have UTC.

But what I don't get is why the logs are not in between 17:00-17:30 (+5 hours) but between 16:00-16:30 (+4 hours)

Comment: Verify your timezone is set correctly in atlas UI, if such a setting exists. If you are shown times that are neither in UTC nor in your timezone (or are emailed such times) I would bring this to attention of atlas support.

Comment: I've changed my GUI timezone this way: `Click in my account name in the upper-right part of Atlas > User Preferences > Personalization > My Time Zone` _When dates are displayed, show them in this timezone._

Comment: I've changed my timezone to match with the date and time shown in the email alerts to be less confusing. That is: _(-04:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)_ and _yyyy-MM-dd - HHzmm_ format. My GUI was set to _(-11:00) Midway Island_ which makes no sense to me.